# navigation bar button text disappears

Tags: swift, xcode

I have 2 nav bar buttons at the top of the screen, one with an image an another with text like so:

[image]

When I present a new view controller with a new nav controller/root controller and then dismiss it, going back to the same view controller, the text disappears like so:

[image]

Here's the code for the view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    setupNavBarButtons()
}

func setupNavBarButtons() {
    let searchImage = UIImage(named: "search_icon")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem

    let filterBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Filter", style: .Plain , target: self, action: #selector(displayFilter))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = filterBarButtonItem
}


func presentAccountController() {
    let accountController = AccountController()
    accountController.listController = self
    let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: accountController
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The controller I'm dismissing to return to the original view controller:

```
class AccountController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupViews()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(245, green: 245, blue: 245)

    let closeButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissController))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButtonItem
}

func dismissController() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've tried calling it in viewWillLoad, viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear.  Still no change and the bug still occurs.

Comment: 'When I present a new view controller with a new nav controller/root controller and then dismiss it, going back to the same view controller" Show how you are doing _that_, please.

Comment: You certainly should not be calling `setupNavBarButtons` in `viewWillAppear`, because `viewWillAppear` can be called many times, whereas you only need this `navigationItem` set up _once_. If this is a view controller in a navigation controller, setting things up once in `viewDidLoad` or your initializer should be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I tried viewDidLoad originally but seems i didn't state that.  Code added to show how I'm return back to the original view controller @matt

Comment: Your code looks fine; thanks for posting it. Can you make a stripped-down version of your app and post it somewhere so I can try it for myself? I can't reproduce the issue based on what you've said, and I don't see what would cause the left bar button item to change its size so as to turn into an ellipsis.

Comment: if you add a button as the customView of the UIBarButtonItem you can set the frame of the button so that it will always have the right width... it is showing "..." because the frame isn't wide enough to fit the text "filter", so setting a button as the customView will allow you to have a hardcoded constant frame size

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and create a frame with a wide `width` when you create the button

```
lazy var filterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30) // Set the width here to make it wider
    button.setTitle("Filter", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

var leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: filterButton)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
}

@objc func filterButtonTapped() {

    print("Filter button tapped")
}
```